# Function gets the number of occurrences of each letter in specified string

Tags: javascript, function, compare

The below function gets the number of occurrences of each letter in the specified string. I understand what is going on until the second for loop.  Why is he adding `"var j = i + 1;"`? and not beginning with `"var j=0"`?

```
function okkur(txt) {
  var str = txt.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "").split("");
  var okk = "";
  var count = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      count = 1;
      for (var j = i + 1; j <= str.length; j++) {
        if (str[i] === str[j]) {
        count++;
        str.splice(j, 1);
        }
      }
      okk = okk.concat(str[i] + " occurs " + count + " times. \n");
    }
return okk;
}
```

Or is there an easier way this function can be accomplished?

Comment: Seems a bit overcomplicated...

Comment: At index i, you have found the first occurrence of a given character, i+1 you are checking for other occurrence leaving aside i.

Comment: If `j` was `0` then it would be counting the same character as a repeat

Comment: I agree.  Easier solution?

Comment: I'd suggest creating an object out of it, so you transform the string into an object of occurrences, where keys are characters, and values are number of occurrences. You can use `reduce` to do this transformation easily. For example `hello` transforms into `{h:1,e:1,l:2,o:1}`. Then you can iterate that object to do the logging.

Comment: @elclanrs I'm new to JS and if you could provide and example this would help me out greatly.

Comment: See Nina Scholz's answer. That's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table for the count of every letter.

This approach uses a single loop for visiting all letters and another loop for generating the result.

```js
function okkur(txt) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);

    txt .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/\s+/g, "")
        .split("")
        .forEach(function (c) {
            hash[c] = (hash[c] || 0) + 1;
        });

    return Object
        .keys(hash)
        .map(function (k) {
            return k + " occurs " + hash[k] + " times.";
        })
        .join('\n');
}

console.log(okkur('stackoverflow'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina but I'm new to JS and haven't gotten to hash tables.

Comment: it's nothing more than an object in javascript. it's like an array, but unsorted and uses strings as accessor instead of indices.

Comment: I got that . I'm getting confused by: .forEach(function (c) {
            hash[c] = (hash[c] || 0) + 1;
        });

Comment: it takes the caracter as key for the object and if that key does not exist, it returns `undefined`, which is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value which is with the following [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) with zero evaluated and returns here zero. later one is added. if the hash value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), a value like a number different from zero, the number is taken and one is added for counting.

Answer (score 0):

By starting the second loop at j = i+1 rather than j = 0, the function is checking all letters after index i.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this so you have a good structure in an object.

```
const charFreq = text => text.split('').reduce((oFrequency, sChar) => {
    oFrequency[sChar] ? oFrequency[sChar]++ : oFrequency[sChar] = 1;
    return oFrequency
}, {})
```

From this structure you can show the output you desire, in your case:

```
Object.keys(charFreq).map(word => `${word} occurs ${charFreq[word]} times`).join('/n')
```

So your final function should be something like this:

```js
function okkur (text) {
   const charFreq = text.split('').reduce((oFrequency, sChar) => {
     oFrequency[sChar] ? oFrequency[sChar]++ : oFrequency[sChar] = 1
     return oFrequency
   }, {})
   return Object.keys(charFreq).map(word => `${word} occurs ${charFreq[word]} times`).join('\n') 
}
    
console.log(okkur('stackoverflow'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to improve on the previous answer I gave. It is basically the same except that there is another function that iterates over every number/letter/symbol you want to check on. It also checks every number/letter/symbol that occurs zero times in the string you are checking.

Do keep in mind that we are supplying the `countTheseCharacters()` function with regular expressions. So if there are special characters you would have to escape them (like the dot and word-breaks).

This probably isn't the most performant solution. But I think it is something you can follow :). You can also replace the regular expressions by whatever and check how many times words (like pizza) exist in a string with the same function.

```js
function countLetters(string, match){
  let regExp = new RegExp(match,"gi");
  let result = string.match(regExp);
  if(result){
    return result.length;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}

function countTheseCharacters(string, regularExpressionsToCheck){
  let countedNumbers = [];
  regularExpressionsToCheck.forEach(function(character){
    countedNumbers.push({
      'character': character,    
      'occurances': countLetters(string, character)
    });
  });
  return countedNumbers;
}

let result = countTheseCharacters("Hello. I like Pizza. Do you like pizza too? The pizzaman, said he does as well!", ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "\\bpizza\\b","\\."]);
console.log(result);
```